# Data map function is not working in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs and using nextjs framework,Right now i am trying to fetch data (url is - https://dummyjson.com/products) using map function but i am getting following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here is my current code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
export default function Test() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>();
  useEffect(() => {
    const callData = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products').then(data => data.json())
      console.log(data);
      setData(data)
    }
    callData()
  }, [])

  return(
    <div>
    {
     data.length ? data.map(({}) => <p key={data.id}>{data.title}</p>) : <h3>There are no records yet</h3>
    }
    </div>)

}
```

Comment: What is unclear from the error message? At least the initial value of data is undefined, which indeed doesn't have a length (or any other) property.

Comment: `data.products.length`? `data` is an object, not an array. And your map also isn't passing any data, should probably be `data.products.map((product) => ....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Initially `data` is `undefined`, so use optional chaining to check nested properties.
- The returned data is an object; you want to access the `products` field.
- Name the first parameter to the `Array#map` callback so you can actually access it.

```
{data?.products?.length ? data.products.map(product => <p key={product.id}>{product.title}</p>) 
       : <h3>There are no records yet</h3>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize `data` state with an empty array:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState<any>([]);
```

You should also change

```js
data.map(({}) => <p key={data.id}>{data.title}</p>)
```

to

```js
data?.map(({id,title}) => <p key={id}>{title}</p>)
```

Comment: i am getting following error
" TypeError: data.map is not a function "

Answer (score 0):

```
//Follow this code. your data in the products array so if you want to map then you have to pass array.

  import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    export default function Test() {
      const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);
      useEffect(() => {
        const callData = async () => {
          const data = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products').then(data => data.json())
          console.log(data);
          setData(data?.products)
        }
        callData()
      }, [])
    
      return(
        <div>
        {
         data.length ? data.map((product) => <p key={product.id}>{product.title}</p>) : <h3>There are no records yet</h3>
        }
        </div>)
    
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code is that you are missing the destructuring of elements in the map function. The correct way would be

```
{
  data.length ? data.map(({title, id}) => <p key={id}>{title}</p>) : 
 <h3>There are no records yet</h3>
}
```